Is it possible to use color names in AS3?
I am trying to find out whether it is possible to use color alias in a string format("orange", 'blue') in Actionscript. Since the main purpose of AS is to produce SFW graphics, there has to be convenient ways to code in similar way as some other programming languages allow to do it.
I would expect this code to produce a blue rectangle:
package
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public class NewActionScriptDesktopProject extends Sprite
    {
        public function NewActionScriptDesktopProject()
        {
                    graphics.beginFill('blue');
                    graphics.drawRect(0,0,300,200);
        }
    }
}

Instead, the code should contain this:
graphics.beginFill(0xe0057B7);


No, but no one could possibly prevent you from creating a class with static constants and use them as such: graphics.beginFill(Color.BLUE);

Wow. I'm from Crimea too and also still using flash. Is there way to send personal messages? It`s huge probability we even know each other. You can just send me telegram message to @IncredibleAwesome if you want =)

No, but you have a couple of options here:

Create a enum class with predefined values:

public class Color {
  static public const SKY_BLUE:uint = 0x0099FF;
}

public class Main extends Sprite {
  public function Main() {
    graphics.beginFill(Color.SKY_BLUE)
  }
}

OR

take it a step further and make a custom class that extends Shape (graphics class is not extendable) and implement custom graphics methods:

  import flash.display.Shape;

  public class GFX extends Shape {
    public function GFX() {

    }

    public function beginFill(colorName:String, alpha:Number=1.0):void {
      graphics.beginFill(colorStringToInt(colorName), alpha);
    }

    public function colorStringToInt(colorString:String):uint {
      if (colorString == "skyblue") {
        return 0x0099FF;
      } else if (colorString == "darkgrey") {
        return 0x3D3D3D;
      } // etc.
    }
  }

Personally, I have taken a more complicated route of the first method and created a custom RGBA class with various color manipulation functions. It's very helpful. Take a look here for some examples on things you can do if you chose option 1.
EDIT: I've committed my colors library in a separate repo along with a swc binary, feel free to use it if you want :)

Nice answer! I am quite surprised that there is no ready library with the predefined colors.

@CrimeaisUkraine I'm glad I could help! honestly, I'm surprised too, I would have thought one would be out there. maybe others thought the same? I've just uploaded it as a tiny library, feel free to use it if you want-- it'll save you some hassle!

Enum class is WAY better than trying to extend Shape or whatever else; because you can reuse color constants everywhere, while extending Shape this way would cause you to replace any shapes (including custom-made Sprites or MCs) everywhere in order to get the requested functionality. Also a color library could be a replica of an RGB conversion of other system colors, say public class PantoneColor { public static const PANTONE001=0x000016; ... } (an example).
